# Cross compiling mySql client in DS-5 eclipse

Tags: mysql, sql, eclipse, autoconf, ds-5

I am trying to access an SQL server from a c/c++ application using mySql on an embedded ARM processor running Debian.  I am compiling using the DS-5 eclipse based IDE (with gcc) under Windows.

The problem is that several of the header files are only present as '.h.in' files which I presume from googling is an autoconf thing.  I am somewhat lost as to how to move forward.

Is autoconf something I can get eclipse to handle, or do I have to do this separately?
How is this configured for the target device rather than the compiling machine?

And as a last question, are there any lighter weight SQL clients that I should be looking at?

Comment: So I have worked around the issue by installing libmysqlclient-dev on the embedded linux, and copying headers and object files into the DS-5 project as described here: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/mysql/setup-mysql-c-access

Comment: I am not entirely content with this although it does appear to work.  I would still like to understand how to build the mysql library in DS-5.